# When I add a file to iTunes library, does iTunes make a copy of it? If yes, where is the copy saved?

Tags: itunes

When I add a file to iTunes library, does iTunes make a copy of it? If yes, where is the copy saved?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the option "Copy files to the iTunes Music folder when adding to library" is activated, iTunes makes a copy.

The default storing location is:

- Windows 7: `\username\Music\iTunes`
- Windows Vista: `\username\My Music\iTunes`
- Windows XP and 2000: `\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\My Music\iTunes`
- MAC OS X: `~/Music/iTunes/`

Comment: You can alter the path by iTunes->Preferences->Advanced->iTunes…Location

Answer (score 2):

There's also a special folder inside your iTunes library folder (Whatever you set it to if not default) called "Automatically Add to iTunes" which is a watched folder. Any time you add a file to it, while iTunes is running, it'll grab it and move it to the correct location. I just use this now. I keep an alias to it in a Stack on my Dock.